# Copying aws snapshot to S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, snapshot

I want to copy an EBS snapshot to my S3 bucket, but i cannot find a way to do it after trying and researching.
I shall be grateful to you for any information that could get me started on a solution.

Comment: You can not. EBS snapshots are stored in S3, but the actual buckets are *not* user accessible.

Answer (score 5):

There is an answer within the AWS forums, but it's rather roundabout:

1. Create a temporary EBS volume from the snapshot. (Snapshots: Actions: Create volume)
2. Create a temporary EC2 Linux instance, install aws cli
3. Attach the volume to the instance and mount. (EBS Volumes: Actions: Attach volume -  must be same availability zone)
4. find name of mounted snapshot volume from lsblk - eg /dev/xvdj
5. Copy the volume contents to your system - eg sudo bash -c "dd if=/dev/xvdj bs=8M | gzip > /home/ubuntu/volbk.gz"
6. Copy your .gz file to S3 -  aws s3 cp ~/volbk.gz s3://my-bucket-name
7. check your s3 bucket contents arrived ok; unmount the snapshot volume
8. Terminate the instance.
9. Delete the snapshot EBS volume.

from here, with my additions (Nov 2 answer):
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=151285

Comment: This looks like a useful process! One question: how would I go about re-creating an instance from the .gz file that I store in S3?

Comment: Beyond the scope of the original question ! But you reverse the process, by unzipping to another temporary EBS volume, using unzip and dd, then using that as an image.

Comment: Re. MikeW's reply about restoring.  You copy that data into a VOLUME not an "image".  The volume can then be attached to an instance.  "image" in AWS is AMI.  Restoration tips:  Attach the root device as /dev/sda1 regardless of what it will really be on the instance.  I find that if you boot an instance with a new root volume, cloud-init will think it's a brand new instance and will clobber a lot of config on your disk.  To prevent that, touch file /etc/cloud/cloud-init.disabled on original disk before you do anything else.

Comment: There's no reason to require local disk space for steps 5+6. Pipe directly from the volume device into your bucket:

  cd /dev && dd bs=8M if=nvme2n1 | xz | aws s3 cp --storage-class DEEP_ARCHIVE - s3://mybuck/vols/rootfs.xz

(xz gives additional 32% space reduction over gzip for my disks)

Answer (score 0):

copy-snapshot command is the AWS CLI command that copies the snapshot of EBS volume and stores it in Amazon S3. You can copy the snapshot within the same region or from one region to another.

This example command copies the snapshot of arbitrary id from one region to another.

`aws --region us-east-1 ec2 copy-snapshot --source-region us-west-2 --source-snapshot-id snap-066877671789bd71b --description "This is my copied snapshot."`

for more info about this refer https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/copy-snapshot.html

Comment: I think there is some misunderstanding of the description for copy-snapshot:

"Copies a point-in-time snapshot of an EBS volume and stores it in Amazon S3"

EBS snapshots by nature are already stored within S3 - this is an incorrect interpretation and the copy-snapshot command only copies the snapshot reference itself.

Answer (score 0):

With Amazon EBS, you can create point-in-time snapshots of volumes, which can be stored in Amazon S3. After you've created a snapshot and it has finished copying to Amazon S3, you can copy it from one AWS region to another, or within the same region. The snapshot copy ID is different than the ID of the original snapshot.
EBS snapshots are stored in Amazon S3. However, you will not find your snapshots in any of your S3 buckets. AWS uses the S3 infrastructure to store your EBS snapshots, but you cannot access them while they reside in S3. 
You can copy the [AWS EBS Snapshot](https://n2ws.com/blog/how-do-ebs-snapshots-ebs-restore-work.html) using either AWS EC2 Console or Command Line.

i) Copy EBS snapshot using Console-:
Open the EC2 console-> Choose snapshot in the navigation pane-> Choose copy from actions list -> In Copy Snapshot dialog box provide necessary details like destination region, description, encryption etc and select copy.

ii) Copy EBS snapshot using Command line-:
Run the below command in AWS CLI:

`aws --region <destination region> ec2 copy-snapshot --source -<source region> --source -snapshot-id <snap-0xyz9999999> --description`