# How to import EC2 snapshot from S3 backup? (AWS CLI import-snapshot)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I want examples on how to backup an EC2 snapshots to S3 bucket, and import it back afterwards.

I found the AWS CLI can export the snapshots to S3, and was explained here
[Copying aws snapshot to S3 bucket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48423813/copying-aws-snapshot-to-s3-bucket)

I also found the import command from AWS CLI reference, but I failed to execute that command, as I don't follow understand the option
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/import-snapshot.html

can someone explain how to use this command? especially on how to specific which file on the S3 bucket to import from?

Answer (score 3):

EC2 snapshots are by default stored on S3 standard storage. However, you **cannot** copy the snapshot to a specific S3 bucket using the AWS CLI.
There may be some third party tool out there somewhere that can do it, but I do not see any reason why you would need to download a snapshot to your s3 bucket? It's like paying for the snapshot twice!!!
Could you mention why you have this requirement? An easier alternate to your problem might exist.

**Note:** 
The two links that you shared in your question, do not copy a snapshot to S3. 
The first link shows how to copy a snapshot from one region to another, while the second link is to export a *disk image* into an EBS snapshot and only the following disk formats are supported for this import:

- Virtual Hard Disk (VHD/VHDX)
- ESX Virtual Machine Disk (VMDK)
- Raw

Answer (score 0):

If I am reading your question correctly, you are having trouble with choosing the bucket from which to restore your backup.  You might find this easier using the EC2 console.

- In the console - Navigation bar - select Snapshots
- Select the snapshot you want to copy from the list
- Choose Copy from Action list, complete the dialog box and click Copy
- When the confirmation dialog box comes up if you click Snapshots then you can monitor the progress.

Here's some additional information on [AWS backups](https://n2ws.com/blog/how-to-guides/automate-amazon-ec2-instance-backup) that might help you.